# Updating OpenGL to 2.0

Tags: opengl

I have v1.1 of the OpenGL driver installed on my Windows 7 machine. (I knew it from [here](https://superuser.com/a/298449/92364))

Now, I want to update it to v2.0.

I also figured that my Intel graphics card driver is old. So, will updating the Intel driver also update OpenGL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Absolutely Yes!

Here is the procedure:

1. Verify your OpenGL version with this program: [OpenGL Extension Viewer](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/download.html)
2. Go to OpenGL [getting started page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started) -- select your graphics card vender, and go to their website to download the latest driver.
3. Install it.

In Intel's case:

1. Automatically get your driver version checked from [here](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/graphics) (Java required)
2. If your driver is older, it will automatically provide you the link to the newer version.
3. Download and install it.